# Using an awk variable mid-word

Tags: variables, awk, command-line

I have a very specific and proprietary use case, so please bear with my bad example and trust me that this makes more sense for my use case.

I have a directory that contains a number of files named `foo`, e.g. `foo_123`, `foo_456`, etc. I am trying to use a variable inside awk to select the one I want, like so:

```
ll | awk -v bar=7 '$NF~/foo_bar/ {print $NF}'
```

This returns nothing, and I'm assuming it's because awk isn't recognizing `bar` as a separate variable rather than part of a word `foo_bar`. How do I get awk to recognize a variable inside of a word?

Comment: `ls -l | awk -v bar=7 '$NF=="foo_" bar'`

Comment: @Luuk yes - that `match()` allows me to target exactly what I'm trying to find inside awk itself. Thanks!

Comment: `bar=7; ls -l "foo_$bar"`

Comment: @GillesQuénot This is not an option. Again, this is an example. I specifically need an awk-based answer. The question is an abstraction of a more proprietary issue that cannot rely on `ll` or `find`. The question says that. The list is already programmatically derived from elsewhere and it is not a list of directory contents.

Comment: Still looking for answer ?

Comment: @dash-o Thanks, no - the linked question has an answer that pointed me to the `match` awk function which was able to do exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options (You seem to be trying to find the file `foo_7`):

1)

```
ll foo* | awk -v bar=7 '$NF ~ foo_ bar {print $NF}'
```

2. 

```
ll foo* | awk -v bar=foo_7 '$NF ~ bar {print $NF}'
```

3. Last option, do not use `awk` for this

```
bar=7; find foo* -name foo_${bar}
```

4. Or even:

```
bar=7; ll foo_${bar}
```

5. No use of `ll` and/or `find`:

```
bar=7; echo -e "foo_1234\nfoo_7\nfoo_456" | grep foo_${bar}
```

Comment: The problem is that in my use case I'm not actually using `ll`, so those solutions don't help. The underscore is part of the name so introducing a space breaks that up. `find` is unhelpful for the same reason.

Comment: All four options are tested locally, and seem to find the file `foo_7`.  Please provide more info in your question, which should be closer to that your are **REALLY** doing.

Comment: But my use case can't actually use `ll` or `find`, which all four options do. Suffice it to say I have a list of items that is programmatically produced in another way.

Comment: Providing more information is not an option. Anything more gives proprietary information. The question is for awk. Please just answer the question as-is instead of trying to find loopholes.